# Xcode projects (iphone) statistics

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am trying to get a quick overview of my iphone projects stats, such as

number of .m/.h/.nib file
LOC

## classes

etc.

I only find Xcode Statistician at http://www.literatureandlatte.com/freestuff/index.html

this looks like doesn't count .nib files

any other useful tools is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could to old school terminal using `wc` (word count) to count lines (the name is a bit misleading, it can could lines too). Maybe piped with a simple `grep` to filter out empty lines. You could also use grep to search for the keyword `@interface`.

Answer (score 0):

You can check and try [Project Statistics for Xcode](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/project-statistics-for-xcode/id650764572?mt=12). It's a very nice piece of software.